How do I handle merged cells in Excel using Pandas parse function?
I have an Excel file with merged columns and rows, and I want to read the excel file and parse it to convert it into a DataFrame.
This is just a small example of what happened because the real data that I have is pretty big with lots of tables.
This is what the Excel file looks like :

When I tried xl = pd.read_excel('file') I got this :

As you can see, the merged rows gave me NaN and the merges cols gave me "Unnamed:".
When I try the parse function (which I use for my data instead of read_excel)
df=[]
xls = pd.ExcelFile('/content/test.xlsx')
entire_sheet = xls.parse(sheet_name='Feuille 1')
df.append(entire_sheet)

I get this :

So it's the same problem with NaN rows and Unnamed cols.
I want the DF in Python to look exactly like the Excel sheet. What should I do?

What do you plan to do with it after it's a dataframe?

@moken I need to get all the tables from the Excel sheet and get them into a dict so I can access any table so that I can use them for an analysis

As the answer from @dydev shows : for Pandas you need specify multi-indexed columns for this form of Excel table. This then will affect how you need to access the DF columns when using names.

Using pd.read_excel
Assuming you have an excel table like this

You can do
df = pd.read_excel('./test.xlsx', index_col=0, header=[0,1])
df.index = df.index.to_series().ffill()

This will give this df

Using pd.Excelfile
xls = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df = xls.parse(index_col=0, header=[0,1])
df.index = df.index.to_series().ffill()


This will indeed work for read_excel() , but what should I use for the Parse() ?

Just pass the same arguments to parse as you would to read_excel apart from the filepath. See the edit.
